# write_database method SingleOutputEcospold2Importer not working for Ecoinvent 3.9

Tags: python, brightway

I am trying to get started doing LCA using the ecoinvent 3.9 database, Brightway2 and Python. I'm not very knowledgeable yet so please bear with me. I am using Brightway2 version 2.4.2. I am trying to import Brightway2 and write it to a regular Brightway database like so:

```
from brightway2 import *

add_ecoinvent_39_biosphere_flows()
pte = r"C:\Users\Joshua Schroijen\ecoinvent\ecoinvent 3.9_cutoff_lci_ecoSpold02"
importer = SingleOutputEcospold2Importer(pte, "ecoinvent39")
importer.apply_strategies()
db = importer.write_database()
```

But this code snippet gives me the following exception on the last line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Joshua Schroijen\.conda\envs\bw2\lib\site-packages\bw2io\importers\base_lci.py", line 237, in write_database
    raise WrongDatabase(error)
bw2io.errors.WrongDatabase: Activity database must be ecoinvent39, but set() was also found
```

I've also noted that before importing ecoinvent 3.9 into a project, one should run

```
add_ecoinvent_39_biosphere_flows()
```

or it won't work. But if I do, that function gives the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joshua Schroijen\leaf-backend\business_logic\ecoinvent.py", line 4, in <module>
    add_ecoinvent_39_biosphere_flows()
  File "C:\Users\Joshua Schroijen\.conda\envs\bw2\lib\site-packages\bw2io\data\__init__.py", line 311, in _add_new_ecoinvent_biosphere_flows
    db.new_activity(**flow).save()
  File "C:\Users\Joshua Schroijen\.conda\envs\bw2\lib\site-packages\bw2data\project.py", line 358, in writable_project
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Joshua Schroijen\.conda\envs\bw2\lib\site-packages\bw2data\backends\peewee\proxies.py", line 160, in save
    raise ValidityError("This activity can't be saved for the "
bw2data.errors.ValidityError: This activity can't be saved for the following reasons
        * ``database`` refers to unknown database
```

Could someone explain what I am doing wrong or seem to be missing?

Thanks in advance!
Joshua Schroijen

Comment: Oh my goodness, that comment is a mess. What I was trying to say is, I don't know if you need an additional backslash included for your directory or if your db_name is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, messy or not ;) I've tried to create the path with pathlib's Path class like so:
pte = Path("C:\\")
pte = pte / "Users" / "Joshua Schroijen" / "ecoinvent" / "ecoinvent 3.9_cutoff_lci_ecoSpold02"
But the same problem persists ...

Comment: I am not seeing a trailing slash at the end, something like this: `Path("C:\\") pte = pte / "Users" / "Joshua Schroijen" / "ecoinvent" / "ecoinvent 3.9_cutoff_lci_ecoSpold02\\"`. I am not sure it'll make a difference (and you'd even assume the module would handle that) but you never know. Give something like that a try, also if you haven't print out the path and make 100% sure that it is what you think it is. Lastly, you can use pathlibs Path to run `.exists()` to make sure youre not insane -> `pte.exists()`.

Comment: I've tried all your suggestions but the problem stays exactly the same, unfortunately.

Comment: If you haven't stumbled across this, it might be worth reading https://github.com/LCA-ActivityBrowser/activity-browser/issues/247

Comment: I appreciate your input. The thing is, I would prefer not using the Activity Browser as I want to create something automatic. I'll check out the Activity Browser implementation of downloading ecoinvent instead of importing it from a local file, though. I think I'll have to do that as a workaround.

Comment: I opened an issue: https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2/issues/54